# How to choose $t$ such that the probability of arriving between 10:40 and 11:00 is maximal?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, normal-distribution, error-function

> Peter has an appointment at $11:00$. He wants to arrive between $10:40$ and $11:00$. Suppose
>   that, if he leaves from home $t$ minutes after $10:00$, then the time of his arrival has normal distribution with mean $t + 30$ and variance $5$ (time is measured in minutes).
>
> $(a)$ How to choose $t$ s.t. the probability of arriving between $10:40$ and $11:00$ is
>   maximum? Justify your statement by proving that the probability is smaller for any
>   other $t$.
>
> $(b)$ With this optimal $t$, given that he arrives after $11:00$, what is the probability that
>   he arrives after $11:10$?

To put in another way, in the case of being late, what is the
probability that the delay is at least ten minutes?

My solution: using The normal law of probability distribution we can found:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{var \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2var^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-t-30)^2}{50}}$$

(a) $P(10:40<x<11:00)=Φ(\frac{10}{5})-Φ(\frac{5}{5})=Φ(2)-Φ(1)=0.9772-0.8413=0.1359$
(b) I dont know

Comment: Show your attempts and clarify your difficulties, please.

Comment: So with a positive probability, Peter can arrive before he leaves home?

Comment: My idea is to use Laplace Integral Theorem, but i dont know how....here is parameter $t$

Comment: So with a positive probability, Peter can arrive before he leaves home? – No)))

Comment: Do you realize that the normal distribution goes both in the positive and the negative direction?  With probability $$\int_{-\infty}^{-30}\frac{e^{-x^2/10}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}dx=\frac{\operatorname{erfc}(3\sqrt{10})}{2}\approx 2.423\times 10^{-41},$$ Peter arrives before leaving home.

Comment: For your attempt, your formula is incorrect.  If $v$ is the variance ($v=\sigma^2$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation), the densitiy function is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi v}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2v)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a)**

From your problem statement, the probability that Peter arrives between 10:40-11:00 if he leaves home $t$ minutes after 10:00 is $$p(t):=\int_{40}^{60}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-t-30)^2}{2\cdot 5}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot 5}}\,\text{d}x=\int_{40}^{60}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-t-30)^2}{10}}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}x\,,$$
whence
$$p'(t)=\int_{40}^{60}\,\frac{(x-t-30)\,\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-t-30)^2}{10}}}{5\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
Write $u:=x-t-30$.  We have
$$p'(t)=\int_{10-t}^{30-t}\,\frac{u\,\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{10}}}{5\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}u.$$

If $t\ge 30$, then clearly, $p'(t)<0$.  If $20<t<30$, then $$p'(t)=\int_{10-t}^{t-30}\,\frac{u\,\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{10}}}{5\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}u\,.$$
If $10<t<20$, then
$$p'(t)=\int_{t-10}^{t-30}\,\frac{u\,\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{10}}}{5\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}u>0\,.$$
If $t\leq 10$, then clearly, $p'(t)>0$.  Therefore, the function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(-\infty,20)$, and strictly decreasing on the interval $t\in(20,\infty)$.  Thus, $p(t)$ is maximized at $t=20$ 
(see also [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1%2F2%28Erf%5B%28t-10%29%2FSqrt%5B10%5D%5D-Erf%5B%28t-30%29%2FSqrt%5B10%5D%5D%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C40%7D%5D)).

The maximum value $p_\text{max}$ of $p(t)$ is given by $p(20)$.  That is,
$$p_\text{max}=\int_{40}^{60}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-20-30)^2}{10}}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}x=\int_{-10}^{+10}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{10}}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}u\,.$$
Consequently, if $v:=\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{10}}$, then
$$p_\text{max}=\int_{-\sqrt{10}}^{+\sqrt{10}}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-v^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\text{d}v=\text{erf}(\sqrt{10})\approx 1-7.74422\times{10}^{-6}\,,$$
where $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

---

**Part (b)**

Denote by $X$ the time in minutes after 10:00 that Peter arrives.  Using $t:=20$, we have
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}[X>60]&=\int_{60}^{\infty}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-20-30)^2}{10}}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}x=\int_{\sqrt{10}}^\infty\,\frac{\text{e}^{-v^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\text{d}v\\&=\frac{\text{erfc}(\sqrt{10})}{2}=\frac{1-p_\text{max}}{2}\approx 3.87211\times 10^{-6}\,,\end{align}$$
where $\text{erfc}$ is the [complementary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html).  Moreover,
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}[X>70]&=\int_{70}^{\infty}\,\frac{\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-20-30)^2}{10}}}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\,\text{d}x=\int_{2\sqrt{10}}^\infty\,\frac{\text{e}^{-v^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\text{d}v\\&=\frac{\text{erfc}(2\sqrt{10})}{2}\approx 1.87205\times 10^{-19}\,.\end{align}$$
That is,
$$\mathbb{P}[X>70|X>60]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X>70]}{\mathbb{P}[X>60]}=\frac{\text{erfc}(2\sqrt{10})}{\text{erfc}(\sqrt{10})}\approx 4.83470\times 10^{-14}\,.$$

In terms of the cumulative distribution function $\Phi$ of the standard normal distribution, we have
$$\text{erf}(z)=2\,\Phi(\sqrt{2}\,z)-1$$
and
$$\text{erfc}(z)=1-\text{erf}(z)=2\,\big(1-\Phi(\sqrt{2}z)\big)$$
for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Ergo,
$$p_\text{max}=2\,\Phi(2\sqrt{5})-1\,,$$
$$\mathbb{P}[X>60]=1-\Phi(2\sqrt{5})\,,$$
$$\mathbb{P}[X>70]=1-\Phi(4\sqrt{5})\,,$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}[X>70|X>60]=\frac{1-\Phi(2\sqrt{5})}{1-\Phi(4\sqrt{5})}\,.$$